# router flux in react native not showing the screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

i have changes the code many times but still its shows the error and shows nothing not login page neither signup page i am confused now pls help.. i am new to react native

1. app.js

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

   import Routes from './src/Routes';

   export default class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
         <StatusBar
           backgroundColor="#002f6c"
           barStyle="light-content"
           />
          <Routes/>
         </View>
       );
     }
   }

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
       flex: 1,
       backgroundColor: '#01579b',
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
     },
   });
   ```

   **this is my Router.js ** this my Router file in which i have given the link

   ```
   import React, {Component} from 'react';
   import {Router, Stack, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

   import Login from './pages/Login';
   import Signup from './pages/Signup';
    export default class Routes extends Component{
   render(){
       return(
          <Router>
          <Stack key="root">
           <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
           <Scene key="register" component={Signup} title="Signup"/>
          </Stack>
          </Router>
           )
   }
   ```

   }

2.this is my login page

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import{Image, StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default class Logo extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
           <Image style={{width:70, height:70}}
            source={require('../images/stgi.jpg')} />
            <Text style={styles.logoText}>Welcome to StigiTel</Text>
            </View>
            )
    }
}
});
```

3.this is my signup page

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import Sform from '../components/Sform';

import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Signup extends Component{
  goBack() {
      Actions.pop();
  }

    render(){
        return(
             <View styles={styles.container}>

              <Logo/>
              <Sform type="Signup"/>
              <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
                    <Text style={styles.signupText}>Already have an account!</Text> 
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goBack}><Text style={styles.signupButton}> SignIn</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

             </View>
            )
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to put Stack tag,
just put like this.

```js
<Router>
<Scene key="root" hideNavBar >
    //put all scene inside it
        <Scene initial key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
        <Scene key="register" component={Signup} title="Signup"/>
</Scene>
</Router>
```

Comment: by removing the stack still the screen is blank and still is not showing any pages...

Comment: You have given class name is logo in Login.js, and provided Component in scene is Login.
Check

Answer (score -1):

You can remove alignItems:'center' from app.js, and that would solve the problem